# Is it bad practice to have a custom "delete" function for polymorphic objects if it makes the code clearer?

Tags: c++, memory-management, polymorphism, destructor

Here's a quick example of what I mean specifically by "polymorphic objects":

```
IFile *file = filesystem->open("myfile.txt");
```

There's two ways to free it (I could pass the pointer back as it if were a handle, but I don't like the idea of using a pointer as a handle):

1. `delete file; //Calls polymorphic destructor`
2. `file->close(); //Calls a polymorphic function`

The first method seems more proper, since that's what destructors are for, but I personally prefer the second one (I'm also used to it as it's how a lot of libraries I've used/use deal with this scenario). But if I'm writing new code and want to go for the "proper" way, which one should I prefer?

Comment: The proper way is to use a resource handle like `std::fstream`.  Also, does your `close` function call `delete this;` internally?

Comment: Neither of them, because that is not C++ style. Use RAII.

Comment: @Nawaz Certain types need to be polymorphic, though. I could use a smart pointer, but only if I use the virtual destructor.

Comment: @Therhang: That is very rare, unless you treat C++ as Java (like many *big* guys, such as google, *does*). What I said is a general rule which you may apply to 90% cases.

Comment: @Nawaz Like I said, this was just an example. I don't use PImpl unless I need to change the implementation of a class at runtime, mostly because it hurts cache performance.